# Delete empty root node in treeView

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, treeview

Let's say I've got tree with 3 categories, each with 3 child nodes. I want to delete root node, when all child nodes gets deleted. I tried something like this:

```
        TreeNode current = treeView1.SelectedNode;
        TreeNode parent  = treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent;

        if (parent.Nodes.Count == 0)
        {
            parent.Nodes.Remove(current);
        }
```

And I placed it in Form1_Load. Unfortunatelly, when all child nodes are gone nothing happens. Is this code correct? Or maybe I misplaced it and I should place it somewhere else?

**edit:** My tree looks like this:

Morning

- brush teeth
- drink coffee

Afternoon

- dinner
- TV

Night

- Sleep

So if I decide to delete "Sleep", I want also delete "Night". But If I decide to delete "TV", I want to keep "Dinner" and "Afternoon".

Comment: You're going from the child _to_ the parent. Assuming there is no `NullReferenceException` thrown, `parent.Nodes.Count` will always be at least 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
{
    if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent == null) treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();
    else if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes.Count == 1) treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Remove();
    else treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the parent is null, then you know that you are on a root node. So that node needs to be removed from the TreeView's Nodes collection directly. Otherwise, you can just remove the selected node from the parent. There's no reason to even look at the Node count.

Now, you also need to check that the current node is not null either; because it's perfectly reasonable to have no node in a tree selected.

```
TreeNode current = treeView1.SelectedNode;
if(current == null)
    return;

TreeNode parent  = treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent;
if (parent == null)
{
    treeView1.Nodes.Remove(current);
}
else
{
    parent.Nodes.Remove(current);
}
```

Comment: But what if root node is not selected after I delete last child node? Is this possible to delete it immediately after last child node gets deleted? Also I don't really understand this snippet - whether parent is null or not, something gets deleted?

Comment: treeview1.SelectedNode may return a null if nothing in the tree is selected.  Also, treeview1.SelectedNode.Parent will return null if SelectedNode is the root node. If you have selected the root node, you want to remove it from the tree; otherwise, you want to remove it from it's parent's node collection.

Comment: This code doesn't work as the OP wants. if the `parent != null`, it can contains 1, 2, 3 ... child nodes, but you just remove the `current node` only in all cases. While in the case of the parent containing only 1 child node, it should be removed away with that only child node.

Comment: You are correct. The original post wasn't very clear as to the exact behavior. The op's edit clarifies that quite nicely.